# How to point existing certificate Manager to newly created application and environment in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-acm

I had already running website. Due to some issue I have to terminate the environment in AWS. After terminating, I did rebuilt via elastic beans and created new environment. My website came back on. But I want this to again forward to my actual domain with godaddy. I used the existing acm certificate in new load balancer for https listener. But Still website getting opened on aws URL, but not with my godaddy domain.

Can you please let me know if I need to change add this certificate anywhere else as well?

Comment: Found the issue. I was doing all correct steps, Needed change the aws new link in godaddy domain.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was doing all correct steps, Needed change the aws new link in godaddy domain.

Also needed to give fully qualified name of my domain in AWS ACM, for https to work.